# Can't access Google Drive via Files

Tags: files, google-drive

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I used to be able to access my Google Drive via Files, but now I can't.

When I hover over the entry me@gmail.com in Files I get Mount and Open me@gmail.com, when I click it I get a spinning (buffering) thing which soon gives - Unable to access "me@gmail.com" Timeout was reached.

I get my gmail OK in https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=km#inbox but can't view Google Drive in Files as I used to be able to. I'm not aware that I've changed anything, but clearly something has changed.

How can I restore this functionality?

Comment: Before anything else check system settings > online accounts. Check the status of your Google account, re-add it if needed.

Comment: Did that before I posted. As I say everything else Google is OK but I can no longer access G Drive via Files.

Comment: Powered PC down, counted to 10 and restarted it.
Still can't access G Drive it still times out, accessing DropBox is fine just G Drive via Files (Nautilus), G Drive via browser is fine.
What is going on?
How do I find out what's causing the timeout and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue cleared up for me when I removed the account from the Settings Online accounts panel and readded it.